# Troubleshooting Polkitd on Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS

Tags: 20.04, gnome, policykit

I'm not sure where to begin... I'm trying to troubleshoot an issue where on the vast number of deployed Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS systems, users never receive a popup asking to enter their password when launching (for example) software-updater.

What happens when a user clicks on "Software Updater" is:

- App Launches
- App says "Checking for updates"
- App says "You are not allowed to perform this action"

What I have been able to narrow it down to is a 'likely' issue between gnome and polkit.  Also for what it's worth, I've also made sure that the user is a member of the 'sudo' group just in case.  I want to also say that most Google hits for this (or similar) issue(s) appear as bugs in much earlier versions of the OS.

Anyway, somewhere along the line I ended up following a thread where they installed `polkit-1-gnome` installed.  Even though my research suggests that this isn't/wasn't needed any longer for Ubuntu 20.04 LTS, out of desperation I went ahead and installed it anyways.

At first, it didn't appear to 'fix' anything until while following the debugging instructions at https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DebuggingPolicykit, when running the following bit of debugging code I did get the legacy **Gnome** popup asking the user for their password:

```
POLKIT_DEBUG=1 G_MESSAGES_DEBUG=all \
/usr/lib/policykit-1-gnome/polkit-gnome-authentication-agent-1 2>&1 \
> /tmp/polkit-gnome-authentication-agent-1.log &
```

I realized in that moment the reason why it *worked* was that I was running the Gnome authentication agent manually.  I then started down the rabbit hole of comparing all of the related permission polkit files between a working system and a non-working system.  For reference the interesting files can be found at:

- /etc/polkit-1/localauthority
- /var/lib/polkit1/localauthority
- /usr/share/polkit1/actions

**Note:** Also for defaults (that come from the files located in /usr/share/polkit1/actions) you can just run the `pkactions --verbose | less` command.

Anyways, this issue is driving me nuts.  I've been comparing all of the *.pkla files between a working system and a non-working system.  I would post error logs but honestly I'm surprised to say that there's minimal logs generated and those that I can find, don't reveal any errors.  I did note that the service is running with a --no-debug flag but I have not yet been able to figure out where to change it to get extra polkitd debug info.

So with all this, I guess if I had to summarize what it is I need help or guidance with on troublshooting...

**Question:**  How can I properly debug `polkitd` to figure out what isn't working properly in Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS?

Any help/advice is truly appreciated!

Comment: Check If the Gnome polkid Agent starts with the Desktop Session. If not Put him in the Autostart.

Comment: It's my understanding that it shouldn't be needed though... not with the base Ubuntu Desktop 20.04.6 LTS install.  Is this true or more specifically... what does it suggest is broken if it only works with the Gnome polkitd agent running?

Comment: I have to admit I use lubuntu. My understanding is the `polkitd - PolicyKit daemon` and an agent has to be run. In my case `lxqt-policykit-agent`